# Different between PWA and Responsive Web App

Tags: responsive-design, progressive-web-apps

I read lot of document in Web but I am confuse.help me and other that what is different between PWA and Responsive Web App

Answer (score 2):

"Responsive" is a word used to describe a web page that can work well (and change it's layout if necessary) for different screen sizes.

A PWA is [a set of web standards](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/checklist) that allows a web page to work as an app, including working offline. It must have certain attributes such as a manifest file, icons and a service worker. It must also be served over an HTTPS connection.